# Open Graph tags on my web page work everywhere but not on Facebook

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, share-open-graph, open-graph-beta

I added the open graph tags to my website. I tested it and it was fine. Link's Open Graph is working in Twitter and Linkedln. But when I share it on Facebook it gives 404. I don't understand why it didn't work. It works on other pages.

Link: https://dergipark.org.tr/tr/pub/ankutbd/issue/59752/577277

Facebok Debugger Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZcy1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. While platforms other than Facebook look at the direct link, facebook references the og:url meta tag. Once I fixed the broken link, the problem went away.